# CSS Border and Circle dynamically on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to achieve this with my current code. I want the 3 sided border on top to dynamically adjust so that it is always perfectly on top of the circles no matter the size of either. Essentially I want the border position to be relative to the circles so that it always looks like the graphic no matter the size of each (These are size changing objects based on user input). This is what I have so far.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaevonz/6rc9jbo3/147/

[image: Example]

```
$(function() {
  $('.circle').hide();
  $('#outer_diameter').on('change', function() {
    var $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
    var $converted = ($outer_diameter * 3.75).toFixed(3);

    if ($outer_diameter > 85) {
      $("#error").text($outer_diameter + " is too big").show();
      return false;
    }

    if ($outer_diameter < 0) {
      $('#error').text('Please input positive integers').show();
      return false;
    }

    console.log($outer_diameter, $converted);
    $('.circle').css({
      height: (2 * $converted),
      width: (2 * $converted),
      top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)",
      left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted) + "px)"
    });
    $('.circle').fadeIn(300);
    $('.circles').css({
      height: (2 * $converted) + 10,
      width: (2 * $converted) + 10
    })
    $('#error').hide();
  })




  $('.circle2').hide();
  $('#inner_diameter').on('change', function() {
    var $outer_diameter = parseFloat($("#outer_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
    var $inner_diameter = parseFloat($("#inner_diameter").val()).toFixed(3);
    var $converted_2 = (($outer_diameter * 3.75) - (2 * ($inner_diameter * 3.75))).toFixed(3);

    if ($outer_diameter > 85) {
      $("#error")
      return false;
    }

    if ($inner_diameter < 0) {
      $('#error').text('Please input positive integers').show();
      return false;
    }

    if ($inner_diameter >= 0.33 * $outer_diameter) {
      $('#error').text('Wall Thickness invalid').show();
      return false;
    }


    console.log($inner_diameter, $converted_2);
    $('.circle2').css({
      height: (2 * $converted_2),
      width: (2 * $converted_2),
      top: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)",
      left: "calc(50% - " + ($converted_2) + "px)"
    });
    $('.circle2').fadeIn(300);
    $('#error').hide();
  })


  $('.border').hide();
  $('#cutter').on('change', function() {
    var $cutter = parseFloat($("#cutter").val()).toFixed(3);
    $('.border').css({
      width: $cutter
    })
    $('.border').fadeIn(300);
  })

});
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>
      Cutter Calculator
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="Calculations">
    <input type="number" id="outer_diameter" placeholder="Enter Outer Diameter"> <br>
    <input type="number" id="inner_diameter" placeholder="Enter Thickness"> <br>
    <input type="number" id="cutter" placeholder="Enter Cutter O.D."> <br>
    <input type="button" id="bttn" name="calculate" value="Calculate">
  </div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="circles">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <span class="circle2"></span>
  </div>
  <p id="error">

  </p>
</div>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.circles {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.border {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it just like placing a div over another? one div has 3 borders whereas the other has border-radius.

Comment: But when the size changes (these are dynamic shapes that change based on user input), the 3 sided border fails to stay perfectly on top of the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of placing div one over another. Using `flex` properties. The sizes are arbitrary.

```js
var t = 0;

function loop() {
  t += 0.01;
  document.querySelector(".div2").style.height = (80 + 40 * Math.sin(t)) + "px"
  document.querySelector(".div2").style.width = (80 + 40 * Math.sin(t)) + "px"

  document.querySelector(".div1").style.height = (40 + 40 * Math.cos(t)) + "px"
  document.querySelector(".div1").style.width = (20 + 20 * Math.sin(t)) + "px"


  requestAnimationFrame(loop);

}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: end;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.elem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}

.div2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: wheat;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.div3 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem div1"></div>
  <div class="elem div2">
    <div class="elem div3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also will this work for size changing shapes based on input from user?

Comment: @Kaevonz flex is the best thing to happen to css since scss. Its a weird one to explain but basically a container element gets the class of display: flex; and then there are many other class options you can add that will determine how the child elements of the flex container are positioned. If you have 10-20 min to learn I recommend playing https://flexboxfroggy.com/ it will give you a brief run down in a visual way. When trying to determine which flex classes to use I ofter just start with flex and click the box beside it in the dev console in inspector!

Comment: Hi, this code doesn't seem to be working in my case because I am using position: absolute in order to create two concentric circles. The position: absolute does not let it be stacked like you have done above, but when I remove it, it does. However, when I remove it, the circles are no longer concentric

Comment: The outer circle doesn't need to be absolute positioned. And once again, flex came to the rescue.